# How to solve the fractional knapsack using heap data structure?

Tags: algorithm

If I use the values of profit/weight and apply build-Max-heap to these values then I will get a max-heap in order(n) time ,Now the confusion is how to delete-the maximum value since after I delete the maximum value how will I come to know what is the weight associated and the profit associated with the node stored in the heap since heap stores only the values associated with profit/weight .

So to perform further calculations like reducing the capacity of the knapsack and adding profit values to already obtained profit values ,how will I do these calculations ?

Comment: which language you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using array of type ‘int' for building max-heap.
Instead what you can do is use array of type ‘struct’ (if you are using C) as below.

```
struct items {
   int profit_by_weight;
   int weight;
};
```

Build the max-heap using the value of ‘profit_by_weight’ (little tricky if you are a beginner) 
and use the value of weight while accessing the item from the heap to do the required calculation.